# Wordpress redirect if not logged in and try to access specific subsite

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users if they're trying to access a specific subsite (ID 13) and they're not logged in. For some reason wp_redirect do and header location don't work, shows me a blank page. I put this into functions.php.

```
function wpse69369_redirect(){
    if(get_current_blog_id() == '13'){
        if(!is_user_logged_in()){
            exit(wp_redirect('http://google.com'));       
        }
    }
add_action( 'init', 'wpse69369_redirect' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your actual code missing the closing bracket on the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot closing tag `}` in your function `wpse69369_redirect` that is why it is showing blank page.
Below is your updated code.

```
function wpse69369_redirect(){
    if(get_current_blog_id() == '13'){
        if(!is_user_logged_in()){
            exit(wp_redirect('http://google.com'));       
        }
    }
 }
add_action( 'init', 'wpse69369_redirect' );
```